# Show 4 images step by step with effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#steps img{
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1.0s linear 0s;
  transition: background-image 1.0s linear 0s;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
</style>
<script>
var i = 0;
var elem;
function nextStep(){
  i++;
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "image"+i+".png"
  img.width = "50px";
  img.height = "50px";
  img.id = "step" + i;
  document.getElementById("steps").appendChild(img);
  elem = document.getElementById(img.id);
  elem.style.display = "inline-block";
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  setTimeout(slide(),5000);
}
function slide(){
  elem.style.opacity = "1";
  if(i > 3){
    clearTimeout(slide());
    clearTimeout(nextStep());
  }
  setTimeout(nextStep(),5000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Steps</h1>
  <div id="steps">
    <script>
      nextStep();
    </script>
  </div>
  <p id="text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 4 images and i want to create and display them step by step with a css3 effect, it start by executing nextStep() function that creates img child to div and change display and opacity. After that slide() is called, the opacity is set to 1 and we call nextStep() again. when i > 3 we stop displaying. When i test it, it displays the 4 images instantly without any effect

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#steps img{
  /*
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1.0s linear 0s;
  transition: background-image 1.0s linear 0s;
  */
  float: left;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
</style>
<script>
var i = 0;
var elem;
//var slide;
//var nextStep;
function nextStep(){
    i++;
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "image"+i+".png"
  img.width = "50px";
  img.height = "50px";
  img.id = "step" + i;
  document.getElementById("steps").appendChild(img);
  elem = document.getElementById(img.id);
  elem.style.display = "inline-block";
    //elem.style.opacity = "0";
  setTimeout(slide(),2000);
}
function slide(){
  //elem.style.opacity = "1";
  if(i < 3){
    //clearTimeout(slide());
    //clearTimeout(nextStep());
    setTimeout(nextStep(),2000);
  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Steps</h1>
  <div id="steps">
    <script>
    document.onload = function (){
        nextStep();
    };
    </script>
  </div>
  <p id="text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always wait for the DOM to be fully loaded before doing any operations on it. Use document.onload to execute your script when the document is loaded :

```
<script>
    document.onload = function (){
        nextSteps()
    };
</script>
```

**Edit :**
There is more issues with your code. The `clearTimeout` function is not needed here. Also, you're not using it right. Quote from the docs at w3schools :

> The clearTimeout() method clears a timer set with the setTimeout()
>   method.
>
> The ID value returned by setTimeout() is used as the parameter for the
>   clearTimeout() method.
>
> Note: To be able to use the clearTimeout() method, you must use a
>   global variable when creating the timeout method:
>
> `myVar = setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);` Then, if the
>   function has not already been executed, you will be able to stop the
>   execution by calling the clearTimeout() method.

Your slide function should look like this :

```
function slide(){
  elem.style.opacity = "1";
  if(i < 3){
      setTimeout(nextStep,5000);
  }
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

`setTimeout` needs a **reference** to a function, e.g the name of the function **without** the parenthesis :

```
setTimeout(nextStep,5000);
```

`nextStep` is a reference to a function
`nextStep()` is the result returned by the function after its execution (undefined in this case)

Comment: thank you for the answer, where shall i put that ? in the head ?

Comment: Use it instead of `<script>nextStep();</script>`

Comment: @Spanpa I've updated my answer to adress other issues in your code

Comment: i corrected my code with your answers but the images doesn't appear now, it's like the function nextStep() is not called